# Rails Overalps DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, datetime

I'm currently trying to check if two datetime ranges overlap. I'm having two problems

First, the overlaps ALWAYS returns false, even when I commit the same start time over and over with a duration of 1 hour (i.e. the start time is 3PM and end time is 4PM, and repeated commits always create a new session without returning true statement via overlap and returning a JSON saying the Trainer is already booked). So the if statement is never hit.
Seconds, Overlaps in rails uses >= in its method, and I'm unable to overwrite this to include > (endpoints don't return true i.e. 3-4PM and 4-5PM shouldn't overlap).

How can I check two datetimes and return true without including endpoints? Am i formatting the dates wrong from JSON? Is my if statement wrong? They are stored in postgresql as datetime with timezones (timestampz).

```
def create_request_iphone

  @start_time = DateTime.parse(params[:start_time])
  @end_time = @start_time + params[:duration].to_f.hour

  #logic to check if trainer is booked at that time
  @trainer = Trainer.where(id: params[:trainers_id]).first
  @booked_session = @trainer.session_details

  //logic to check if trainer has booked sessions that overlap

  @booked_session = @trainer.session_details

  @booked_session.each do |aSession|
    if (aSession.start_time..aSession.end_time).overlaps?(@start_time..@end_time)
        respond_to do |format|
          msg = {:status => "FAILURE", :message => "TRAINER ALREADY BOOKED"}
          format.json  { render :json => msg }
        end
        return
    end
  end

  @session_detail = SessionDetail.new(trainers_id: @trainer.id)

   unless(!@session_detail.save)
      respond_to do |format|
        msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :message => @session_detail.as_json)
        format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
      end
     end
   end
```

Comment: Ended up using the following

'  def overlap?(x,y)
    (x.first - y.end) * (y.first - x.end) > 0
  end'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the triple-dot `...` version of [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html), which excludes the right end-point.

For example:

```
(1..4).overlaps? (4..8)
# => true

(1...4).overlaps? (4..8)
# => false
```

Comment: What about: (4...8).overlaps?(1..4) ? Wouldn't that not work ? Colud (4...8).overlaps?(1...4) work i.e. triple dots on both ?

Comment: Also its still always returning true so this isn't working. IT should return false

Comment: sorry, meant its always returning false. It may be a formatting issue

Comment: This excludes one of the boundaries only. The OP wants to exclude both boundaries in both ranges. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Humza It is unnecessary to exclude both end points. For the application that the OP wants, using Range with the triple dots `...` is sufficient.

Comment: @Matt, you're right - the triple-dot range should suffice in the OP's use-case.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the triple ... suggestion by @matt , I found the following which also works

```
def overlap?(x,y)
 (x.first - y.end) * (y.first - x.end) > 0
end
```

The key was to drop the >= that was included in active record.

http://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails